# Laravel whereJsonContains query not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to this query:

```
$order = Order::whereJsonContains('products->id',$serial_no)->first();
```

But it's not working please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

```
[
  {
    "id": 24,
    "name": "test product",
    "qnt": 3,
    "sale_price": 18,
    "buy_price": 14,
    "stock": 3,
    "total": 54,
    "company": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "test company",
      "contact": "01521482467,5555555",
      "address": "fdsa fdsa fdsa fdsa fdsa",
      "is_active": 1
    },
    "brand": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test Brand",
      "is_active": 1
    },
    "category": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test",
      "is_active": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 28,
    "name": "test2",
    "qnt": 1,
    "sale_price": 18,
    "buy_price": 12,
    "stock": 1,
    "total": 18,
    "company": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "test company",
      "contact": "01521482467,5555555",
      "address": "fdsa fdsa fdsa fdsa fdsa",
      "is_active": 1
    },
    "brand": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test Brand",
      "is_active": 1
    },
    "category": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Test2",
      "is_active": 1
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Try these

```
$order = Order::whereJsonContains('products', ['id' => $serial_no])->first();
```

When your json is look like

```
{
    "id": 24,
    "name": "test product",
    "qnt": 3,
    "sale_price": 18,
    "buy_price": 14,
    "stock": 3,
    "total": 54,
    "company": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "test company",
      "contact": "01521482467,5555555",
      "address": "fdsa fdsa fdsa fdsa fdsa",
      "is_active": 1
 }
```

Then your code will work properly.
But your `JSON` is in `Array` Like

```
[
   {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "test product",
        "qnt": 3,
        "sale_price": 18,
        "buy_price": 14,
        "stock": 3,
        "total": 54,
        "company": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "test company",
          "contact": "01521482467,5555555",
          "address": "fdsa fdsa fdsa fdsa fdsa",
          "is_active": 1
     }
]
```

So you can solve your problem using these syntax

```
$order = Order::whereJsonContains('field_name', ['object_key' => 'object_value'])->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **get()** instead of **first()** and try again.

Answer (score 0):

@md abdul karim Please check your mysql version , well that mysql json_contains work with mysql 5.7 or grater version.

Comment: mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.25-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)

Comment: I dont know how but my system show this :(